# GAE Webapp: the cost of importing a bunch of request handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

My python GAE app's central application file looks like this:

```
import webapp2
import homepage
import user_auth
import user_confirm
import admin_user
import admin_config
import config

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                (user_auth.get_login_url(), user_auth.LoginHandler),
                                (user_auth.get_logout_url(), user_auth.LogoutHandler),
                                ("/user/confirm", user_confirm.UserConfirmHandler),
                                ("/admin/config", admin_config.AdminConfigHandler),
                                ("/admin/user/add", admin_user.AdminAddUserHandler),
                                ("/admin/user", admin_user.AdminUserHandler),
                                ("/", homepage.HomepageHandler),
                            ], debug=True)
```

As you can see, I must import a bunch of request handlers, but for each request, only one of them is used, the other imports are just useless!
That's a big waste of memory and performance because those unnecessary imports also import other things on their own. Does Google App Engine have some "caching" mechanism or something that makes these unnecessary imports negligible? I think not.

How can I avoid them? I just haven't found out the way to import 1 Request Handler per request. If I put all the routing to app.yaml, that would work the way I want, but it makes things complex because I must write `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(...` for every request handler file and repeat those boring urls twice (both in the python file and in app.yaml).

Comment: They're not being imported on every request - only on the first one for each instance.

Comment: @NickJohnson: What do you mean by "each instance"? Can you please explain?
I know you work for GAE, so you must be right :D

Comment: An instance is when your application loads for the first time.  After it is loaded it will stay loaded as long as you keep a warm up request going or you have sufficient requests.  If you don't have a request for awhile Google will spin down your instance.  The next time your app receives a request it will start a new instance and all your handlers will be reloaded unless you use the webapp2 lazy handlers.  (Although there are some gotchas you need to watch out for so be certain to read the lazy handler documentation you have linked in your answer below.)

Comment: @MarkFinch: many thanks for the precious knowledge :D

Answer (score 3):

Found the way here, already built into webapp2
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#lazy-handlers